# Change model colors in multiplot (ggplot2)

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, coefplot

I am using the `multiplot` function in the `coefplot` package, which uses `ggplot2` as a base. I am plotting multiple models but can't figure out how to change the color of each model. For example:

```
require(coefplot)
data(diamonds)
model1 <- lm(price ~ carat + cut, data=diamonds)
model2 <- lm(price ~ carat + cut + color, data=diamonds)
multiplot(model1, model2)
# multiplot(model1, model2, colors = c("blue", "red"))  # Doesn't Work
```

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add `scale_color`

```
multiplot(model1, model2)+scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue"))
```

If it is ggplot base function, then try to use the ggplot settigns